# How small should be a ParDo operation for good performance and scaling of a beam job?

Tags: apache-beam

In a dataflow pipeline, there are multiple small filters that I want to apply on the data stream (ParDo functions).

The filter operations are not CPU intensive. For performance and scaling, should I do all filters in a single ParDo or each ParDo per filter operation (cleaner code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the runner that you are using supports fusion and you apply the filters directly after each other with no combiner / GBK then your code will be executed within a single fused step.

[From the Beam SDK Javadocs:](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.html)

**Optimization**

Beam runners may choose to apply optimizations to a pipeline before it is executed. A key optimization, fusion, relates to ParDo operations. If one ParDo operation produces a PCollection that is then consumed as the main input of another ParDo operation, the two ParDo operations will be fused together into a single ParDo operation and run in a single pass; this is "producer-consumer fusion".

I would recommend going with the cleaner code option and letting the runner optimise the execution.